# Why chord and tangent method does not give further points on Fermat's curve?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

(0,1) and (1,0) are two rational points on x^3 + y^3= 1. But why doesn't chord and tangent method yield any further points on the curve?

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens? Both points you mentioned are points of inflection, so their tangents just detect them again. The chord through the two points detects the point at infinity as another rational point.

Answer (score 1):

There are no additional rational points on the curve, since the equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no non-trivial solutions in integers. This is the case $n=3$ of Fermat's Last Theorem, probably first proved by Euler.